# Totals not changing with repeater filtering

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

We're migrating from NAV 2009 R2 to NAV 2016 and I'm having an issue with a page.

I have a repeater with several columns the user can filter. There a $ totals in the group below the repeater that should change based on what is presented within the repeater grid after filtering.

Thanks for any insight anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "totaling" procedure (that will add the values from the current record to global variables which are displayed at the bottom of the page) and call it from the OnAfterGetRecord() trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a FlowField in the table that your page is based on. The FlowField should Sum the columns you need and then just add the newly made field to the group in your page. Ofcourse you would have to keep the filters in mind.

The other option is that you make a global variable (for example Total) on the page and a function that calculates the total sum of a given column or columns and stores it in the variable. Add the variable as a field within the page group and also make sure the value updates after any change.